# Why is vnc not able to change the keyboard layout when the main display can?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, vnc, input-language, fcitx

Clarifying the quesition: fcitx does not execute automatically on tigervnc and I have even unsuccessfully added fcitx to xstartup. What should I do to execute fcitx automatically? I did successfully manually execute fcitx and changed the language, but not automatically on startup. 
In my case, I use tigervnc server on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I currently use fcitx for korean and interchange with English.
However, if I access the main physical display, fcitx works correctly, and I can change between Korean & English, but fcitx simply does not work on the vnc. 
Are there any good workarounds to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (This should work for all fcitx users):
First, make sure that fcitx is your default input method.
Then, on `~/.vnc/xstartup` add the following code after the line that starts the desktop environment. (eg. `startxfce4 &` or `gnome-session &` or etc based on your environment)

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
fcitx &
```

Comment: What does it mean and how it works?